# createElement every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to createElement every 3 seconds I'm using a setTimeOut function but when I run the code, after 3 seconds it just spams the script and creates loads of elements instead of creating one every 3 seconds.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var elementDiv = document.createElement("div");
    elementDiv.className = "chat-message error";
    elementDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chatBoxMessage));
    document.getElementById('message-window').appendChild(elementDiv);
},3000);
```

-Updated full code with amendments

```
function chatAlert () {
setInterval(function() {
    var elementDiv = document.createElement("div");
    elementDiv.className = "chat-message error";
    elementDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chatBoxMessage));
    document.getElementById('message-window').appendChild(elementDiv);
},3000);
```

}

Comment: instead of parsing all over again the whole document in search for an element, cache your selectors: `var msgWin = document.getElementById('message-window');` and than use `msgWin` inside the setInterval

Comment: _"after 3 seconds it just spams the script and creates loads of elements"_ I can't reproduce this. The code you posted creates  the elements only once. What's `chatBoxMessage`?

Comment: chatBoxMessage is a variable that stores a string which is the message, even using the `setInterval` method instead of `timeout` still delays the message for 3 seconds before reproducing it 1000s of times

Comment: How about you create a stack snippet or jsFiddle that reproduces the behavior because what you've posted so far doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function() {
    var elementDiv = document.createElement("div");
    elementDiv.className = "chat-message error";
    elementDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chatBoxMessage));
    document.getElementById('message-window').appendChild(elementDiv);
},3000);
```

`setTimeout` introduces delay in executing the callback, whereas, `setInterval` executes the callback after every certain interval.

Comment: It's still being spammed after a 3 second delay even while using this `setInterval` method, I'm not sure if this matters but the `setInterval` is inside a function which is being repeatedly called while a boolean is true. I've updated the original post with the full code

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` only executes once. You want to use `setInterval` instead.